# How to .map() array inside array like parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My consult return an json object with array inside array... My `console.log` is like this:

```
item1: false
item2: 999
item3: Array(3)
          0: {id: 1589, data: "..."}
          1: {id: 1587, data: "..."}
```

I need get the `item3` array and pass like a parameter, so I tried it:

```
componentDidMount() {
   //... 
  this.myFunction(myJson.item3.map(content => content.id))     
}

myFunction = id => {
   //something....
}
```

But, my `content` variable is returned like `not defined´.

I tried use different ways to do this, but without successful.

What I'm doing of wrong?

How I can get `map()` my array `item3` and pass like a parameter to `myFunction`?

Comment: You’re passing an array of ids to ‘myFunction’. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Can you add the code where you console log your `content` in relation to your CDM function. Maybe CDM does not have access to `content`.

Comment: Can you also give expected output. It's unclear what you actually want.

Comment: Yuch. Why are people using `a = b => {` in classes? What's wrong with `a(b) {`?

Comment: @WillHoskings Its a function, not a class, and this is the new standard.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: It's a React component, and they're obviously using the arrow function syntax in a class for some reason.

Comment: Yes, react components can have functions within them. And this syntax is still very much acceptable and useful for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   //... 
  myJson.item3.map(content => this.myFunction(content.id))     
}

myFunction = id => {
   //something....
}
```

What you are doing in your code is mapping over the array and then doing nothing. Then calling myFunction of undefined since the map never returns anything. What you want to do instead is map the function to each item in the array to get the id. So you would call map and then in the map call myFunction for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown enough, I have this code working:

```js
let things = {
  thing1: false,
  thing2: '999',
  thing3: [{ id: 1589, data: "..." },
          { id: 1587, data: "..." }]
}

const myFunction = id => {
  console.log(id)
}

myFunction(things.thing3.map(content => content.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is structured how you think it is, this should work just fine.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  item1: false,
  item2: 999,
  item3: [
    {id: 1589, data: "..."},
    {id: 1587, data: "..."}
  ]
};

const ids = jsonObj.item3.map( o => o.id );

console.log(ids);
```

If that still doesn't get you your array of `ids` please post the exact return of what your json object looks like.